# XML feeds and namespaces with PHP, SimpleXML and Xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath, namespaces

Hi I have been struggling with this puzzle for some time now how to get data out of this embedded namespaces here is the xml feed I have cut it down to make easier to read

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cf="http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/rss/core/2005" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:sc="http://schemas.sage.com/sc/2009" xmlns:crm="http://schemas.sage.com/crmErp/2008" xmlns:sdatasync="http://schemas.sage.com/sdata/sync/2008/1" xmlns:sdata="http://schemas.sage.com/sdata/2008/1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:sme="http://schemas.sage.com/sdata/sme/2007" xmlns:http="http://schemas.sage.com/sdata/http/2008/1">
  <author />
  <category term="tradingAccount" />
  <generator />
  <subtitle>Provides a feed containing tradingAccount details</subtitle>
  <title>Sage Accounts 50 | tradingAccount - Practice Accounts                                                    </title>
  <entry>
    <author />
    <content type="html"><![CDATA[<html>

</html>]]></content>
    <id>http://computer_1:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/{FF476636-D4AF-4191-BDE4-891EDA349A68}/tradingAccountCustomer(58b10585-63d4-4bb8-adb3-7096d9b055d9)?format=atomentry</id>
    <link href="http://computer_1:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/-/tradingAccountCustomer" rel="via" type="application/atom+xml" />
     <published>2015-03-13T21:28:59.000+00:00</published>
    <updated>2015-07-01T21:33:13.000+01:00</updated>
    <http:httpStatus>200</http:httpStatus>
    <sdata:payload>
      <crm:tradingAccount sdata:url="http://computer_1:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/{FF476636-D4AF-4191-BDE4-891EDA349A68}/tradingAccountCustomer(58b10585-63d4-4bb8-adb3-7096d9b055d9)?format=atomentry" sdata:uuid="58b10585-63d4-4bb8-adb3-7096d9b055d9">
        <crm:active>true</crm:active>
        <crm:customerSupplierFlag>Customer</crm:customerSupplierFlag>
        <crm:companyPersonFlag>Company</crm:companyPersonFlag>
        <crm:invoiceTradingAccount xsi:nil="true" />
        <crm:openedDate>2013-04-22</crm:openedDate>
        <crm:reference>AAA</crm:reference>
        <crm:name>BBB</crm:name>
      </crm:tradingAccount>
    </sdata:payload>
  </entry>
  <opensearch:totalResults>118</opensearch:totalResults>
  <opensearch:startIndex>1</opensearch:startIndex>
  <opensearch:itemsPerPage>118</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
</feed>
```

I am trying to access the `<crm:reference><crm:name><crm:openedDate>` namespace but failing I have looked at similar projects but I think its a namespace within a namespace
here is my attempt at parsing the data

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file("sage.xml");
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('sdata', 'http://schemas.sage.com/sdata/sync/2008/1');
foreach($xml->xpath("//sdata:payload") as $entry) {
    $entry->registerXPathNamespace('sdata', 'http://schemas.sage.com/sdata/sync/2008/1');
    $entry->registerXPathNamespace('crm', 'http://schemas.sage.com/crmErp/2008');
    $content = $entry->xpath("/sdata:payload/crm:tradingAccount/crm:active");
    //$article = feed->xpath("/sdata:payload/crm:tradingAccount/crm:active");
    foreach($content as $c) { 
       // echo $c->reference . " | " . $c->name . "/" . $c->accountOpenedDate . "<br />\n";
    }
}
var_dump($content);
var_dump($c);
```

any pointers to my problem would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($xml->xpath("//sdata:payload") as $entry) {
    // xpath here must be from payload to tradingAccount
    $content = $entry->xpath("./crm:tradingAccount");
    foreach($content as $c) {
       // Make set of children with prefix crm
       $nodes = $c->children('crm', true); 
       echo $nodes->reference . " | " . $nodes->name . " / " . $nodes->openedDate . "<br />\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be as simple as:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("sage.xml");

$reference = $xml->xpath("//crm:reference");
$name = $xml->xpath("//crm:name");
$openedDate = $xml->xpath("//crm:openedDate");

echo "reference: ". $reference[0] . "<br>";
echo "name: ". $name[0] . "<br>";
echo "openedDate: ". $openedDate[0] . "<br>";
```

If you would like to use a foreach loop to get all children of 'crm' you can do the following. You need atleast 5.2.0 if you want to set children to prefix (true)

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("sage.xml");

foreach($xml->xpath("//crm:tradingAccount") as $entry) {    
       $child = $entry->children('crm', true);         
}

echo "reference: ". $child->reference . "<br>";
echo "name: ". $child->name . "<br>";
echo "openedDate: ". $child->openedDate . "<br>";
```

Comment: thank you this has been bothering ever since I answered Ajking11 question on "problems displaying json data retrieved using php curl"